# Comparing values of same column depending on values in different column from the same pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

Here is my data frame:

| month | year | category | size | sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 2022 | shirt | M | 52 |
| 5 | 2022 | shirt | M | 45 |
| 1 | 2022 | shirt | S | 61 |
| 12 | 2021 | shirt | S | 89 |
| 12 | 2021 | pant | S | 72 |
| 7 | 2022 | shirt | M | 42 |
| 8 | 2022 | shirt | M | 55 |
| 8 | 2022 | pants | 41 | 9 |

What I would like is to roll up previous month to another column:

Like this:

| current_month_year | previous_month_year | category | size | sold_current | sold_previous |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6-2022 | 5-2022 | shirt | M | 52 | 45 |
| 1-2022 | 12-2021 | shirt | S | 61 | 89 |
| 12-2021 |  | pant | S | 72 | 0 |
| 8-2022 | 7-2022 | shirt | M | 55 | 42 |
| 8-2022 |  | pant | 41 | 9 | 0 |

how would I do this?

I have no idea how to do this so don't have any code to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new DataFrame with the output columns you want and iterate over the original DataFrame to filter the size and category in adjacent months to get the previous sales. The current sales and the rest of the rows are easy to add by simply copying from one DataFrame to the other and doing a small transformation to calculate the previous month.

I would do something like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [6, 5, 1, 12, 12, 7, 8, 8], 'year': [2022, 2022, 2022, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022], 'category': ['shirt', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'pant', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'pants'], 'size': ['M', 'M', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'M', 'M', '41'], 'sold': [52, 45, 61, 89, 72, 42, 55, 9]})

df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['current_month_year', 'previous_month_year', 'category', 'size', 'sold_current', 'sold_previous'])

df_new['current_month_year'] = df['month'].astype(str) + '-' + df['year'].astype(str)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['month'] == 1:
        df_new.loc[index, 'previous_month_year'] = '12-' + str(row['year'] - 1)
    else:
        df_new.loc[index, 'previous_month_year'] = str(row['month'] - 1) + '-' + str(row['year'])

df_new['category'] = df['category']
df_new['size'] = df['size']
df_new['sold_current'] = df['sold']

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    sold_previous = df[(df['month'].astype(str) + '-' + df['year'].astype(str)) == df_new.loc[index, 'previous_month_year']]
    sold_previous = sold_previous[sold_previous['category'] == df_new.loc[index, 'category']]
    sold_previous = sold_previous[sold_previous['size'] == df_new.loc[index, 'size']]
    sold_previous = sold_previous['sold'].values
    if sold_previous.size > 0:
        df_new.loc[index, 'sold_previous'] = sold_previous[0]
    else:
        df_new.loc[index, 'sold_previous'] = 0
```

This would be the output:

```
current_month_year  previous_month_year category    size    sold_current    sold_previous
0   6-2022  5-2022  shirt   M   52  45
1   5-2022  4-2022  shirt   M   45  0
2   1-2022  12-2021 shirt   S   61  89
3   12-2021 11-2021 shirt   S   89  0
4   12-2021 11-2021 pant    S   72  0
5   7-2022  6-2022  shirt   M   42  52
6   8-2022  7-2022  shirt   M   55  42
7   8-2022  7-2022  pants   41  9   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Will start by creating the column `current_month_year` based on the columns `month` and `year`

```
df['current_month_year'] = df['month'].astype(str) + '-' + df['year'].astype(str)

[Out]:
   month  year category size  sold current_month_year
0      6  2022    shirt    M    52             6-2022
1      5  2022    shirt    M    45             5-2022
2      1  2022    shirt    S    61             1-2022
3     12  2021    shirt    S    89            12-2021
4     12  2021     pant    S    72            12-2021
```

Then, let's now focus on the column `previous_month_year`. The approach will be similar at first, but then we will add the conditions

```
df['previous_month_year'] = df['month'].astype(str) + '-' + df['year'].astype(str)

[Out]:
   month  year category size  sold current_month_year previous_month_year
0      6  2022    shirt    M    52             6-2022              6-2022
1      5  2022    shirt    M    45             5-2022              5-2022
2      1  2022    shirt    S    61             1-2022              1-2022
3     12  2021    shirt    S    89            12-2021             12-2021
4     12  2021     pant    S    72            12-2021             12-2021
```

Then let's add the conditions:

• If `month` is `1` (January), the previous month is `12` (December) with less `1` `year`

```
df.loc[df['month'] == 1, 'previous_month_year'] = '12-' + (df['year'] - 1).astype(str)

[Out]:
   month  year category size  sold current_month_year previous_month_year
0      6  2022    shirt    M    52             6-2022              6-2022
1      5  2022    shirt    M    45             5-2022              5-2022
2      1  2022    shirt    S    61             1-2022             12-2021
3     12  2021    shirt    S    89            12-2021             12-2021
4     12  2021     pant    S    72            12-2021             12-2021
```

• If `month` is different than `1` (January), then subtract `1` to the `month` and the `year`

```
df.loc[df['month'] != 1, 'previous_month_year'] = (df['month'] - 1).astype(str) + '-' + df['year'].astype(str)

[Out]:
   month  year category size  sold current_month_year previous_month_year
0      6  2022    shirt    M    52             6-2022              5-2022
1      5  2022    shirt    M    45             5-2022              4-2022
2      1  2022    shirt    S    61             1-2022             12-2021
3     12  2021    shirt    S    89            12-2021             11-2021
4     12  2021     pant    S    72            12-2021             11-2021
5      7  2022    shirt    M    42             7-2022              6-2022
6      8  2022    shirt    M    55             8-2022              7-2022
7      8  2022    pants   41     9             8-2022              7-2022
```

Finally, as OP wants to have the column `sold_previous`  to show the number of `sold` items in the `previous_month_year` for a given `category` in a given `current_month_year`, the following will do the work (if there isn't `previous_month_year`, the value of the cell will stay `0` - as defined before the loop):

```
df['sold_previous'] = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'current_month_year'] == df.loc[i, 'previous_month_year']:
        df.loc[i, 'sold_previous'] = 0
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'sold_previous'] = df.loc[(df['current_month_year'] == df.loc[i, 'previous_month_year']) & (df['category'] == df.loc[i, 'category']), 'sold'].sum()

[Out]:
   month  year category  ... current_month_year  previous_month_year sold_previous
0      6  2022    shirt  ...             6-2022               5-2022            45
1      5  2022    shirt  ...             5-2022               4-2022             0
2      1  2022    shirt  ...             1-2022              12-2021            89
3     12  2021    shirt  ...            12-2021              11-2021             0
4     12  2021     pant  ...            12-2021              11-2021             0
5      7  2022    shirt  ...             7-2022               6-2022            52
6      8  2022    shirt  ...             8-2022               7-2022            42
7      8  2022    pants  ...             8-2022               7-2022             0
```

If one wants to change columns names, for example `sold` to `sold_current`, one can do the following

```
df['sold_current'] = df['sold']
```